# MYSQL join query not using index, even though force index added

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query to test FORCE INDEX in MYSQL but it doesn't work.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM `zt_story_classification` as a
JOIN zt_story_plan as b FORCE INDEX (story_version_id_idx) 
ON b.story_version_id = a.id
```

`id` is the PRIMARY KEY of table a. And b have an index for column `story_version_id`. They're of same type (int).
I execute the query with EXPLAIN, it shows me this:

[image: Explain shows the story_version_id_idx is not used]

Here are table creation queries. Do you have any idea? Thanks for help!

```
CREATE TABLE `zentao`.`zt_story_classification`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `story_id` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `product`(`product`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 14010 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `zentao`.`zt_story_plan`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `story_version_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `story_version_id_idx`(`story_version_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 4282 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Comment: It will probably be highly depending on which table has more data. Forcing an index is usually just a temporary work around. Is there actual performance problems in the query without it?

Comment: For this query no. But for another query with same issue yes.. For another one it scans two tables, one has 1800 rows and another 10000 rows. A not complicated query takes 3s. Locally I didn't reproduce such issue. What rules could there be to limit index using in MYSQL? I'm asking DBA also

Comment: Now the problem seems linked with DB rules. Locally that query could use index naturally without FORCE INDEX. BUT with online db, it doesn't use index even with FORCE INDEX..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query optimizer has decided to read from b and join a, so the index hint for joining b is irrelevant.

You can force the table order to be unchanged with `select straight_join * ...`

Comment: Yes.. there is no condition on b's column so there is nothing to do with b's index. Thanks for your hint